# Sidepanel does not disappear after clicking somewhere else

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on `alpha.dubaiexporters.com`.

```
http://alpha.dubaiexporters.com/aboutus.aspx
```

Upon resizing the browser, the blue button panel comes and after clicking on it, it shows the navigation side bar.The issue is that after clicking somewhere else, it does not disappear.

[image]

[image]

I don't seem to find the issue here. The home page is not creating any problems. Rest pages do.

Comment: If you don't want downvotes [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Post a [mcve] inside it, so it remains relevant no matter what happens to the website you're working on. Ask a question that, when answered, will help both you and future visitors with a similar problem. In current form answering the question primarily helps you, and that's not a very big incentive for anyone to answer.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu...i wont repeat it again..but this issue really screwd my head..i am trying to sort out this issue since morning...but dint gt success..

Comment: That is irrelevant, @chetan. If you want help you should provide help. Make your question **useful, answerable and relevant** if you're looking for serious answers. It's how [so] works and why it works. Make your question look like it was asked by you, the developer, not by the client. I don't want to be harsh. I'm trying to help.

Comment: sorry @AndreiGheorghiu..i wont repeat it again..

Answer (score 1):

You can add to end of your code when you activate the menu and

```
$(".container").on("click", function(){
   $(".menu-btn").click();
});
```

And inside the menu-btn.click() add a $(".container").off(); so it toggles the behaviour.